# How many shaders should i use?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, shader

I've already written my own 3D Game Engine in Java but I want to rewrite it for optimization.

My engine looks like this:

There is an abstract superclass called RenderSystem.
Code :

```
public abstract class RenderSystem<T> {
    public abstract void addElement(T element);
    public abstract void enableSystem();
    public abstract void disableSystem();
    protected abstract void cleanUp();
}
```

Every RenderSystem extends "RenderSystem". 
For every different Material there is a render system and therefore a shader.
I've created an enum that stores what parts of my material are enabled (bump_map, displacement_map etc.)

It looks like this: (i missed out all the getter and setter stuff)
Code :

```
public enum MaterialType{

COLOR_MAT (1,false,false,false,false,MasterRenderer.entity_system,null);

private MaterialType(int index, boolean use_bump_map, boolean use_displacement_map, boolean use_normal_map,
        boolean use_specular_map, RenderSystem<?> default_system, RenderSystem<?> instanced_system) {
    this.index = index;
    this.use_bump_map = use_bump_map;
    this.use_displacement_map = use_displacement_map;
    this.use_normal_map = use_normal_map;
    this.use_specular_map = use_specular_map;
    this.default_system = default_system;
    this.instanced_system = instanced_system;
}

private final int index;
private final boolean use_bump_map;
private final boolean use_displacement_map;
private final boolean use_normal_map;
private final boolean use_specular_map;

private final RenderSystem<?> default_system;
private final RenderSystem<?> instanced_system;
   //...................
```

In this example, I stored only one Material in it, it does not use any of those maps except the color_map (which is always enabled).
Furthermore, it stores the Systems that deals with those kinds of entities that use that material.
Code :
MasterRenderer.entity_system

This will be done with everything else, I will add a skydome material, particle material etc. This is all straight forward but my question now is, which shaders do I need ?

Shall I write one shader for every entity, (entities are those who are created by using an obj. file, no particles etc. included)
or one shader for normal rendering without bump_maps and all that stuff, and one shader for my material with a normal_map ?
That would mean that I render every entity with that one shader, even if it does not have any of those maps it has to calculate that stuff.

Furthermore I want to add a BoneSystem to my characters. I guess that's something that should have its own shader ?
Below I will list what shaders I would create:

- EntityShader (only colormap)
- EntityShader (colormap and normalmap)
- EntityShader (colormap and specularmap)
- EntityShader (colormap, normalmap and specularmap)
- EntityShader (colormap, bumpmap, displacementmap, normalmap,
  specularmap)
- CharacterShader (only colormap with bones)
- SkydomeShader (only colormap), renders the sky
- ParticleShader (probably only colormap BUT INSTANCED!!)
- TerrainShader (probably will get its own material to do stuff like
  blending)
- ShadowShader (takes entities and no other map, renders only the depth
  to a framebuffer)
- WaterShader (if I am really bored and have nothing else to do)
- And finally: InstancedEntityShader (only colormap but instanced)

I might add some postProcessing effects but that's not safe yet.

I just want to know if THAT structure is okay and effective or should I change anything?

Also, how many shaders are normally used in games?

Comment: Does the saying "the more, the merrier" apply to shaders?

Comment: Depends, hugh amount of generalizion causes bad performance. You should Not have to many ofcourse because that takes to much Time to switch between them

Comment: What is the target device you want to run your engine on ? 
Desktop computer (high end or average ?) or mobile phone/tablet ?

Comment: desktop, probably only pc